# Why hyperlink (a tag) in JTextPane stays in center (center aligment)

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

i have implemented two methods in order to add text and hyperlinks in a ***JTextPane***. The problem is that the hyperlink is shown with center alignment but not the text (i want both to have left alignment).

#### The methods are:

```
public void addText (String log, Color c, boolean bold) {
    StyledDocument doc = jTextPane.getStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attrs, "Calibri");
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrs, 13);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, c);
    StyleConstants.setBold(attrs, bold);
    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), log, attrs);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrameLog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void addHyperlink (URL url, String text) {
    StyledDocument doc = jTextPane.getStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet hrefAttr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    hrefAttr.addAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF, url.toString());

    SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    attrs.addAttribute(HTML.Tag.A, hrefAttr);

    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attrs, "Calibri");
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrs, 13);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, Color.blue);

    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, attrs);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

#### And the result is this:

[image: the problem[1]]

#### Full problem demo code-snippet [HERE](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/cqNWWN3Q).

**Does anyone know how can i fix this issue?**

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. That is create a frame with a JTextPane and the code to add the text to the text pane.

Comment: The image is demonstrating the problem. The way to create it is just call this two methods along with a jtextpane on a simple JFrame. Is really there a meaning to post the full code?

Comment: It allows the users to test the code, play around with it to find the error because such errors can't always be seen by just looking at the code.

Comment: `The way to create it is just call this two methods along with a jtextpane on a simple JFrame.` - exactly. The assumption is you have already tested the code in this simple situation to make sure other code in your application isn't affecting this part of the code.  So there is no need for us to create code that you already have. You are asking the question. Make it easy for us to  copy/paste/compile/test so that we can problem solve using real code.

Comment: *"to post the full code"* Nobody suggested that, and that you made that incorrect assumption indicates you did not read the linked document. -1 for 'poor research'. Reading the content of offered links should be part of that research.

Comment: Ok, ok, i updated the post, adding the minimal demo code guys, don't sue me. I added a code snippet for everyone who wants to test the methods i posted and see where lies the problem with the alignment.

Comment: 1) the code should be posted in the forum, not on an external website. 2) the problem has nothing to do with the hyperlink. Comment out all the addHyperlink(..) methods and you still have a problem with spacing for the normal text. I have never had much luck using HTML but maybe this info will help others provide a suggestion.

Comment: I couldn't post the whole snippet because of the restriction, because then most of my post would be code. But i didn't have anything more to say about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [camickr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879183/2962656) i managed to find a solution using the HTMLEditorKit class :)

I replaced my previous methods with one generic, which appends some html code into the JTextPane.

#### The new method is:

```
    public void appendTextPane (String html) {
        HTMLEditorKit editor = (HTMLEditorKit) jTextPane.getEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) jTextPane.getDocument();
        String TAG;
        if (html.charAt(0) != '<') {
            TAG = "";
        } else {
            int nextSpaceIdx = html.indexOf(" ");
            int nextBrcktIdx = html.indexOf(">");
            TAG = html.substring(1, nextBrcktIdx < nextSpaceIdx ? nextBrcktIdx : nextSpaceIdx);
        }
//        System.out.println(jTextPane.getText());
        try {
            editor.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), html.replaceAll(" ", "&#160;"), 0, 0, HTML.getTag(TAG));
        } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
        }
    }
```

#### And the fixed preview is this:

[fixed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQEAX.jpg)

#### Full solution demo code-snippet:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class SolutionDemo {

    private JFrame jFrame;
    private JTextPane jTextPane;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane;

    public SolutionDemo () {
        //CREATE THE COMPONENTS AND SHOW THE FRAME WINDOW
        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jTextPane = new JTextPane();
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextPane);
        jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        jFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //I NEED IT TO BE HTML SO THE HYPERLINK TO BE CLICKABLE
        jTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
        jTextPane.setEditable(false);
        jTextPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
        jFrame.add(jScrollPane);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //ADD LISTENER IN ORDER TO OPEN THE LINK ON BROWSER WHEN CLICKED
        jTextPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            public void hyperlinkUpdate (HyperlinkEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(evt.getURL().toURI());
                        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void init () {
        //SET GLOBAL STYLES
        jTextPane.setText(""
                + "<head>"
                + " <style type=\"text/css\">"
                + "     body{ "
                + "         color: green;"
                + "         font-family: calibri"
                + "     }"
                + " </style>"
                + "</head>");
        //ADD SOME TEXT AND HYPERLINKS
        String url = "https://www.example.com";
        appendTextPane("No tag must be inserted first in order to custom header work with this impl ");
        appendTextPane("<span>BLAH blah BLAH blah BLAH blah BLAH blah </span>");
        appendTextPane("<span style=\"color:red\">BLAH blah BLAH blah BLAH blah BLAH blah </span>");
        appendTextPane("<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>");
        appendTextPane("<span> BLAH blah BLAH blah BLAH blah BLAH blah <a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a></span>");
        appendTextPane("With no tag the text goes to next line <a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>");
    }

    public void appendTextPane (String html) {
        HTMLEditorKit editor = (HTMLEditorKit) jTextPane.getEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) jTextPane.getDocument();
        String TAG;
        if (html.charAt(0) != '<') {
            TAG = "";
        } else {
            int nextSpaceIdx = html.indexOf(" ");
            int nextBrcktIdx = html.indexOf(">");
            TAG = html.substring(1, nextBrcktIdx < nextSpaceIdx ? nextBrcktIdx : nextSpaceIdx);
        }
//        System.out.println(jTextPane.getText());
        try {
            //REPLACE SPACES WITH ITS NUMERIC ENTITY REFERENCE IN ORDER TO SHOW ALL THE EXISTING SPACES 
            editor.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), html.replaceAll(" ", "&#160;"), 0, 0, HTML.getTag(TAG));
        } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new SolutionDemo().init();
    }
}
```

**Thank you [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr)!**  Unfortunately i can't upvote your answer due to lack of reputation..

Comment: (1+) for posting your solution. Glad you could make sense of my ugly code.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth I have some old (ugly) code lying around from when I tried to manipulate HTML text in a document.

I used methods other than `insertString(...)`. Maybe this will give you some ideas?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class TextPaneHTML extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JTextPane textPane;
    HTMLEditorKit editorKit;
    HTMLDocument doc;
    Element root;

    public TextPaneHTML()
    {
        textPane = new JTextPane();
//      textPane.setEditable( false );
        textPane.setContentType( "text/html" );
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit)textPane.getEditorKit();
        doc = (HTMLDocument)textPane.getDocument();
        root = doc.getDefaultRootElement();


        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textPane.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
        textPane.setText( "<html><body>Hello world I want some long text <a href=\"http://answers.polldaddy.com/poll/1742928/\">Do you like polls</a> to it wraps to a new line World!</body></html>" );


//      textPane.setCaretPosition(7);
//      textPane.setText( "" );
//      printInfo();

        //  Add text pane to frame

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        //  Add a append button
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 0) );
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        createButton("Normal", buttonPanel);
        createButton("Styled", buttonPanel);
        createButton("B1", buttonPanel);
        createButton("B2", buttonPanel);
        createButton("B3", buttonPanel);


        try
        {
        HTMLDocument.Iterator it = doc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A);

        while (it.isValid())
        {
            SimpleAttributeSet s = (SimpleAttributeSet)it.getAttributes();
            System.out.println(s);
            s.removeAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
            System.out.println( s.getClass().getName());
            String href = (String)s.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
            int start = it.getStartOffset();
            int end = it.getEndOffset();
            String text = doc.getText(start, end - start);
            System.out.println( href + " : " + text );
            it.next();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {};

    }

    public void createButton(String text, JPanel panel)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener( this );
        panel.add( button );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String command = ae.getActionCommand();
        String text;

        try
        {
            if ("Normal".equals( command ))
            {
                text = "normal text";
                editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), text, 0, 0, null);
            }

            if ("Styled".equals( command ))
            {
//                  text = "<font size=5 color=red>font and color test</font>";
                text = "<a href=\"abc\">hyperlink</a>";
                editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), text, 0, 0, null);
//              doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, null);
//              try {
//                  editorKit.read(new StringReader(text), doc, doc.getLength());
//              } catch (Exception e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//              }

            }

            if ("B1".equals( command ))
            {
//                  text = "<br>B1";
                text = "<a href=\"abc\">hyperlink</a>";
                Element element = root.getElement(1);
                doc.insertBeforeEnd(element, text);
            }

            if ("B2".equals( command ))
            {
                Element element = root.getElement(1);
                text = "<br>B2-after start";
                doc.insertAfterStart(element, text);
                // why doesn't this work
                text = "<br>B2-before end";
                doc.insertBeforeEnd(element, text);
            }

            if ("B3".equals( command ))
            {
//                  text = "<p>B3</p>";
//              editorKit.insertHTML(doc, textPane.getCaretPosition(), text, 0, 0, HTML.Tag.P);
                text = "<a href=\"abc\">hyperlink</a>";
                editorKit.insertHTML(doc, textPane.getCaretPosition(), text, 0, 0, HTML.Tag.A);
//              doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, null);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
//              BadLocationException ble = (BadLocationException)e;
//              System.out.println(e + " : " + ble.offsetRequested());
                System.out.println(e);
        }

//      System.out.println( command + ": -----------" );
//      System.out.println( "Elements: " + root.getElementCount() );
//      System.out.println( root.getElement(0).getAttributes() );
//      System.out.println( root.getElement(1).getAttributes() );
        try
        {
            System.out.println( "textPane: " + textPane.getText() );
            System.out.println( "Document: " + textPane.getDocument().getText(0, textPane.getDocument().getLength()) );
        }
        catch(Exception e2) {}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
        TextPaneHTML frame = new TextPaneHTML();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(50, 120);
        frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```